# Look up items in same table from relationship table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query where I search for a value contained in a table (called objects), look up it's id in a table called relationships and find the id's of related objects and look them up in the original table.

```
Objects                            Relationships

ID         Value                   ID    RelatedToID   RelatedFromID
1          Name                    A     2             1
2          Name1                   B     3             1
3          Name2                   C     4             1
4          Name3                   D     2             3
```

Query Name > return Name1, Name2, Name3

To add some background SCCM stores windows updates and update groups within the same table and creates relationships between objects in the same table and stores them in a separate table.

Comment: What's the part causing your difficulty?

Comment: if i search for the name (which i know) all i get back are 3 instances of the name i searched for, rather than the 3 related items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Objects o1
INNER JOIN RelationShips r ON
o1.ID = r.RelatedFromID
INNER JOIN Objects o2 ON
r.RelatedToId = o2.ID
WHERE o1.Value LIKE '%The value you are searching for%'
```